# Where during my expect script is is it timing out?

Tags: timeout, expect

Within my expect script expect_after to catch the timeout coming from BadPromptPassword,  however how do I return that this was the place that my expect script timed out?  I've played with expect_out and it doesnt give me what I need... Any help appreciated.  Thanks

```
spawn telnet 172.27.228.239
expect {
    timeout { puts "Timed out waiting for response from telnet ('172.27.228.230',)."; exit 1}
    "Password:" { send "lab\r"; }
    "\[>#\]"
};

send "en\r"
expect_after {
    timeout {
      puts "a default timeout clause for all subsequent expect commands ";
      exit 1
    }
}
expect "#>"
send "admin"
expect "BadPromptPassword:"
send "lab\r"
close
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack

```
expect_after {
    timeout {
        puts "timed-out expecting $pattern";
        exit 1
    }
}

set pattern "#>"
expect $pattern
send "admin"

set pattern "BadPromptPassword:"
expect $pattern
send "lab\r"
```